# Disabling the 'Save' and 'Save and continue editing' buttons for a model in the Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm writing the admin view for the model in my Django application. This admin view should a be a read-only view. I don't want anyone creating or deleting records either. I've managed to prevent user's from creating and deleting records. Here's my model's admin class:

```
class EmailAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """
    Admin part for managing the the Email model
    """
    list_display = ['to', 'subject', 'ok',]
    list_filter = ['ok']
    readonly_fields = ['when', 'to', 'subject', 'body', 'ok']
    search_fields = ['subject', 'body', 'to']

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return False
```

When the user clicks on a record in the admin, it takes him to the detail view where he can't edit anything as all the fields are read-only but he continues to see two buttons on the lower-right hand side of the admin console that read 'Save' and 'Save and continue editing'. Is it possible to remove these links? I'd like to have a total read-only admin view.

Thanks.

Comment: if you don't want any thing in the change view than why not you use has_change_permission.

Comment: Ah, so there is one like that. I couldn't Google it up. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: It doesn't seem to to work. It disables the entire view. ANy other ideas?